# Accessing nested property from {{first}}{{last}} array handlebars-helper

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I can't figure out how to access the nested property on an array using the `{{first}}` and `{{last}}` handlebars-helpers. I have an array,

`"test" : [{
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : 2
    },
    {
        "a" : 2,
        "b" : 3
    }]`

I have tried using array syntax `{{{{last test}}.0.a}}` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
{{#each test}}
 {{#if @last}} 
  {{this.a}}
 {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Tested using http://tryhandlebarsjs.com